# AFrame: particle system component package is not working

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

I am building a basic Web VR application using AFrame, https://aframe.io/. I am trying to to a frame particle components following this example, https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/introduction/entity-component-system.html#example. Basically, I copied the code as mentioned on the official documentation.

This is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-animation-component@3.2.1/dist/aframe-animation-component.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-particle-system-component@1.0.x/dist/aframe-particle-system-component.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-extras.ocean@%5E3.5.x/dist/aframe-extras.ocean.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-gradient-sky@1.3.0/dist/gradientsky.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-entity id="rain" particle-system="preset: rain; color: #24CAFF; particleCount: 5000"></a-entity>

      <a-entity id="sphere" geometry="primitive: sphere"
                material="color: #EFEFEF; shader: flat"
                position="0 0.15 -5"
                light="type: point; intensity: 5"
                animation="property: position; easing: easeInOutQuad; dir: alternate; dur: 1000; to: 0 -0.10 -5; loop: true"></a-entity>

      <a-entity id="ocean" ocean="density: 20; width: 50; depth: 50; speed: 4"
                material="color: #9CE3F9; opacity: 0.75; metalness: 0; roughness: 1"
                rotation="-90 0 0"></a-entity>

      <a-entity id="sky" geometry="primitive: sphere; radius: 5000"
                material="shader: gradient; topColor: 235 235 245; bottomColor: 185 185 210"
                scale="-1 1 1"></a-entity>

      <a-entity id="light" light="type: ambient; color: #888"></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run my application in the Chrome web browser, I am getting the following error in the console and I cannot see the particles.

[image]

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with `aframe-extras.ocean`. It is based on an older version of aframe (and three.js) and uses a `mergeVertices` function that has changed in newer versions. That error breaks the rest of the application.

You can either downgrade your aframe version to 0.9.0, or fork and update `aframe-extras.ocean`. I would usually suggest you report this to the maintainers of aframe-extras, but they may not be active enough to fix it in a timely manner.